# edit RStudio project options from command line

Tags: r, rstudio

I am setting up an R project for multiple people with little to no experience with R/RStudio, and need a .Rprofile to be sourced when the project is opened. Currently I have them source a script for most of the setup but still need to have them manually edit the project options. I would like to uncheck "Disable .Rprofile execution..." project option using a script, but cannot find a command that does this. Disabling .Rprofile execution does not appear to be a global option, and it is unclear to me how this preference is saved in the project. Any thoughts on how I could go about doing this?

[image: RStudio project options]

Comment: I just tested, and the project started with that unchecked. Are you seeing different behavior?

Comment: Yep, every user I've helped has the box checked. Must be the version of Rstudio available through my agency.

Comment: I wonder if your Rstudio is launched with additional arguments... If you were to run `commandArgs()` in Rstudio, do you see any additional arguments tagging along? Mine was only `Rstudio` and `--interactive`

Comment: That's what I am getting as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When RStudio creates a project named `foo`, it creates a file called `foo.Rproj`, which is actually a text file, containing several project options.  By default, there's nothing there about executing `.Rprofile`, but if someone checks the box you've marked in your question, they'll get a line

```
DisableExecuteRprofile: Yes
```

in that file.  If you delete that line you'll effectively uncheck the box.  This appears to work even if the user has the project open, though not if they have the dialog open to set the option.

Edited to add:  this is explicitly allowed, according to this message:  https://community.rstudio.com/t/editing-rproj-files-from-the-console/31800 .